# Mysql DB table structure for the excel table having multiple sub columns under single colum

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

how to represent the below Excel table as a Mysql DB structure format where in a column has multiple sub columns as given below

```
Name             Mon-Fri                   Sat                Sun       
            Asia      UK    USA      Asia   UK  USA     Asia    UK  USA
Name1       0.25     0.25   0.5       0.5   -   -        -     0.5   -
Name2       0.5      0.5     1         1    -   -        -      -    - 
Name3       0.25     0.25   0.5       0.5   -   -        -     0.5   -
```

Comment: You can not literally have sub columns. The approach in you case is two or three separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

You usually do this by adding a `Time` column to the data and "normalize" it:

```
Name   Region   Time    Amount
------|-------|--------|-------
Name1   Asia    Mon-Fri 0.25
Name1   Asia    Sat     0.5
Name1   Asia    Sun     -
Name2   UK      Mon-Fri 0.25
Name2   UK      Sat     -
...
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization as well

Answer (score 0):

For this first create a table of Days

### tbl_days

id,
dayname

Then Create a group with these days. Group may be with one day or multiple days

### tbl_group

id,
groupname,
days (make it comma separted with day id)

Then create a country master

### tbl_countries

id,
country_name

Then assign the calculation like below

### tbl_calculation

id,
group_id,
country_id,
value (nullable)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with following Table Structure

tbl_Region -

```
 ID , Name
    1,UK
    2,Asia
```

tbl_Date_allocation -

```
    ID,WEEK_DAY_NAME
    1, Mon
    2 , Wed
    3 ,...
```

tbl_types

```
Id, Name
1, Name 1
2, Name 2
......
```

tbl_allocation

```
id,region_id,date_allocation_id,type_id,value
1,1,2,1,0.25

id - auto increment 
region_id,date_allocation_id,type_id - foreign keys to other table
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have are two entities: something-that-has-a-name, let's call them *People*, and Geographic Area -- three of which are the values Asia, UK and USA. Then you have represented relationships between People and GAs. As seen from your data, a Person may relate to 0 or more GAs and a GA may relate to 0 or more people. Such a many to many relationship is maintained by an intersection or cross table (two names for the same thing). You further show two aspects of this relationship: a term ("Mon-Fri", "Sat" and "Sun") and an Amount.

The fact that *Term* values are days of the week are not really significant. There are three possible values so let's call them 1, 2 and 3. *Amount* looks like it could be any floating point value.

```
create table PersonGO(
  PersonID  int not null references People( ID ),
  GAID      int not null references Areas( ID ),
  Term      int not null check( Term in (1, 2, 3 )),
  Amount    float not null,
  constraint PK_PersonGO primary key( PersonID, GRID )
);
```

The data stored in such table would look like this:

```
PersonID  GAID  Term  Amount
       1     1     1  0.25   -- Name1 Asia Mon-Fri
       1     1     2  0.50   -- Name1 Asia Sat
       1     2     1  0.25   -- Name1 UK   Mon-Fri
       1     2     3  0.50   -- Name1 UK   Sun
       1     3     1  0.50   -- Name1 USA  Mon-Fri
       2     1     1  0.50   -- Name2 Asia Mon-Fri
       2     1     2  1.00   -- Name2 Asia Sat
       2     2     1  0.50   -- Name2 UK   Mon-Fri
       2     3     1  1.00   -- Name2 USA  Mon-Fri
       3     1     1  0.25   -- Name3 Asia Mon-Fri
       3     1     2  0.50   -- Name3 Asia Sat
       3     2     1  0.25   -- Name3 UK   Mon-Fri
       3     2     3  0.50   -- Name3 UK   Sun
       3     3     1  0.50   -- Name3 USA  Mon-Fri
```

Where there is no relationship for a particular person to a particular area on a particular term, such as Name1 with UK on Saturday, there is no entry. You would *not* have an entry with 0 or `NULL` in the Amount field. That would be unnecessary.

As your sample data looks like one week's worth of data and there would probably be one set of these entries for each week of a year, the table might have another field, *WeekNum*, with possible values such as 201601 for the first week of 2016, 201602 for the second week and so forth. You have a good deal of flexibility here. You could just as well merge this with the *Term* field: 2016011 for Mon-Fri of the first week, 2016012 for Sunday of the first week and so on. You could come up with something entirely different. Whatever makes the most sense to you.